# Qlikview aggregation

Tags: aggregate-functions, qlikview, qliksense

I have a table like the below. For each date there is a have a product. And I want to aggregate by the product and carry forward the total. But the total is limited to 0. For each day and product, I want to aggregate and carry forward the aggregate.

| Date | product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/Jan/2021 | a | 300 |
| 05/Jan/2021 | a | 200 |
| 05/Jan/2021 | b | 500 |
| 04/Jan/2021 | a | -100 |
| 04/Jan/2021 | b | 1100 |
| 03/Jan/2021 | a | -500 |
| 03/Jan/2021 | b | -900 |
| 02/Jan/2021 | a | 200 |
| 02/Jan/2021 | b | 500 |
| 01/Jan/2021 | a | 100 |

For the latest date I want to see the output as below:

| Date | product | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/Jan/2021 | a | 500 |
| 06/Jan/2021 | b | 1600 |

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get total = 500 for product `a` for `06/jan/2021`?

Comment: 1st jan the total for product a is 100. For 2nd Jan, the total is 100+200=300. For 3rd Jan the total goes to 300-500=-200. however since we have a floor of 0, the total gets rest to 0. So for 3rd Jan the total is 0. On 4th jan the total is 0-100 =0. Here again the total is reset to 0. 5th Jan total is 0+200=200. 6th Jan total is 200+300=500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the script below.
Ive annotated the code to explain each step.

If you reload the script the result table will be:

[image: TotalAmount table]

The basic idea is:

- order the records by product and date (ascending)
- while loading the ordered table aggregate the records (by product)
- if the sum is `< 0` then return 0, else continue with the aggregation
- once we have the aggregation find the max date for each product and flag these records. The max date record will contain the total amount (per product)
- filter the flagged records and load them in the final table

Annotated load script:

```
RawData:
Load * inline [
Date       , product, Amount
06/Jan/2021, a      , 300
05/Jan/2021, a      , 200
05/Jan/2021, b      , 500
04/Jan/2021, a      , -100
04/Jan/2021, b      , 1100
03/Jan/2021, a      , -500
03/Jan/2021, b      , -900
02/Jan/2021, a      , 200
02/Jan/2021, b      , 500
01/Jan/2021, a      , 100
];

NoConcatenate

// Order the data by product and date in ascending order
OrderedData:
Load
  date(date#(Date, 'DD/MMM/YYYY')) as Date, // convert to date
  product,
  Amount
Resident 
  RawData
Order By 
  product,
  Date asc
;

// we dont need RawData table anymore
Drop Table RawData;

// CalculatedAmount calculation/logic:
// * if the current value for product is not equal to the prvious value
//   get the current amount. This the case where the producs are "switched"
// * if the sum of the current Amount value + the previous CalculatedAmount value
//   is less than 0 then return 0
// * for the rest of the cases - return the aggregated amount - current Amount
//   added to the previous CalculatedAmount
CalculatedAmount:
Load 
  Date,
  product,
  Amount,
  if( product <> peek('product'), Amount,
    if( Amount + peek('CalculatedAmount') < 0, 0,
  Amount + peek('CalculatedAmount')
  )) as CalculatedAmount
Resident 
  OrderedData
;

// we dont need OrderedData anymore
Drop Table OrderedData;

// use the CalculatedAmount table to find the max date for each product
// these records are containing the total amount for each product
// flag these records with 1 and join the result table back to
// CalculatedAmount table
join (CalculatedAmount)
Load 
  max(Date) as Date,
  product,
  1 as isTotalAmount
Resident
  CalculatedAmount
Group By 
  product
;

// the final table - filter CalculatedAmount table to return
// only the records for which isTotalAmount = 1
TotalAmount:
Load 
  Date,
  product,
  CalculatedAmount as TotalAmount
Resident
  CalculatedAmount
Where
  isTotalAmount = 1
;

// we dont need CalculatedAmount table anymore
Drop Table CalculatedAmount;
```